# Using overflow hidden when all elements are positioned absolutely

Tags: css, position, overflow

OK, so here it the thing...

I cannot get `overflow:hidden` to work.
I need to apply it to the body so that the `.content` div is not visible before the animation ends...

Here is the jsFiddle, you should see what the problem is right away:

http://jsfiddle.net/bzbNg/

EDIT: OK so it was pointed out to me that I was not specific enough:

I want the .content div to slide out with the body but not change it's height, so as if it was just pulled out of a pocket, if you know what i mean...

Comment: absolute position on body ? Uhm...

Comment: @AndreaLigios it's just to reduce code... Why create a div inside body if you could do it to the body itself

Comment: Because absolute position strips the element from the flow... then you will have basically no flow :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite understand, why u want to use `overflow: hidden`. Since you want the `.content` to be shown when animation ends, why dont you hide it in css and `.fadeIn()` in `.animate()` callback? Is that what you want to achieve? Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/bzbNg/2/

Comment: You see the .content below the footer element, but I want it to reveal as the nav and the footer split appart

Comment: @neustroev.ai , your Fiddle is the same of the OP. You forgot to save it ? :)

Comment: @neustroev.ai it does solve the problem but it is not the effect i want to achieve

Comment: @DinoPrašo then try to be more specific about the behaviour you expect.